# MVC3 - Create a custom calendar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, calendar, fullcalendar

I would like to create a fully customizable calendar in MVC3, C#, Razorviews. Does anyone have any good links on how I could accomplish this? I do not want to use the datepicker controls for this because I want more functionality to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several calendar controls, in fact you have the tag for one in your tags.

[FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)